# What implementation is more efficient to count occurrences in a number sample?

Tags: java, performance, counter, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I'm programming a Bayesian Network which will allow me to diagnose (based on the most probable diagnosis) a tumor as benign or malign. The network will learn from a large set of samples which include the results of a set of 10 medical tests, plus the diagnosis. These results will be discrete, ranging from 0 to a maximum value.

In this case, given that I will have to program a counter (`int[]` sample tests, `int[]` values), in order to count the occurrences of `values[i]` in the samples `tests[i]`, which is the most efficient implementation to choose for the class "sample"?

Currently I have implemented an `ArrayList<int[]>()`.This is how I programmed it. However, given that I'm expecting to get around 300 sets of samples (results of 10 different tests+diagnosis) I was looking for the most efficient way to implement the "Sample" class (I called it "amostra").

```
    public class Amostra implements AmostraInt {
    private ArrayList<int []> dados;

    public Amostra() {
        this.dados = new ArrayList<int []>();
    }

    public int[] count (int[] var, int []val) {
        int i=0;
        int[]ocorre = new int[var.length] ;
        while (i< dados.size()) {
            int j=0;
            while (j<var.length) {
                if (dados.get(i)[var[j]]==val[j])
                    ocorre[j]+=1;
                j++;
            } 
            i++;
            }           
        return ocorre;
```

Comment: Could you post an [mcve]. It's not entirely clear what you're doing.

Comment: Quick question, just want to make sure, your algorithm has proven to be logically accurate and you just want to see if further refactoring can be done on it to improve performance?

Comment: @JoseMartinez yes. It works but I was wondering if there's any implementation, other than an ArrayList < int[] >(), which will allow me to count occurrences more efficiently.

Comment: @Persixty thanks! I added the example to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here are some minor improvements.  Changed while loop to for loop.  Replaced multiple calls to `dados.get(i)` with one per outer loop iteration.  This won't change the speed, since the JVM would optimize the call to `dados.get(i)` but it does make the code look more concise.

I do not know enough about the data to find a way to replace the double loop.  Essentially it looks like the double loop is needed.

```
public int[] count(int[] var, int[] val) {
    int[] ocorre = new int[var.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < dados.size(); i++) {
        int[] dado = dados.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < var.length; j++) {
            if (dado[var[j]] == val[j]) {
                ocorre[j] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return ocorre;
}
```